# How to add entity with existing attached to it

Tags: entity-framework

I want to add entity payment object, containing EXISTING Currency object to EF database:

```
public Payment()
{
   int Id {get;set;}
   public int Value {get;set;}
   public Currency SelectedCurrency{get;set;}
}

public Currency()
{
    int Id {get;set;}
    string Name;
}
```

Suppose that I have existing Currency attached to new entity Payment(). When I add such entity Payment(), the error appears

**Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Currency'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.MwbeCurrency'. The duplicate key value is (GBP).\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}**

How to add higher-level entity with attached existing lower-level entity?

My code for adding entity is:

```
public virtual TEntity Add(TEntity entity)
        {
            return DbSet.Add(entity);
        }

public void SaveChanges()
        {
            Context.SaveChanges();            
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you retrieved `Currency` with a different instance than the one that retrieved `Payment` and did something like this :

```
payment.Currency = retrievedCurrency;
```

Therefore, the `Payment` context things that `Currency` is a new object and tries to persist it. Since it already exists, you are getting a PRIMARY KEY violation.

If you want to persist `Payment` correctly, add the following lines:

```
if (payment.Currency != null && payment.Currency.Id != 0) 
{
    context.Entry(payment.Currency).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
}
```

although it would probably be cleaner if you retrieved `Payment` and `Currency` with the same context, so you can persist them appropriately.

Comment: @Circuler ;) another similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29898462/how-to-update-existing-entity-containing-not-updated-sub-entity/29909909#29909909   Would you look at this?;)

Answer (score 0):

Calling `DbSet.Add(entity)` adds the entire graph for persistence, which means it will go through all the navigation properties of `entity` and set each one's state to `EntityState.Added`.

While the other answer might work, a better approach is to change the way you are adding the objects, and be explicit about what entities you are adding / updating / etc.

To do this, change:

```
public virtual void Add(TEntity entity)
{
    DbSet.Add(entity);
}
```

To:

```
public virtual void Add(TEntity entity)
{
    context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
}
```

This will add only the supplied entity. If one of your navigation properties objects is also new, you call `.Add(entity)` on it as well.

If you do need to add the entire graph in other situations, you can add an additional method that works the way your original one does, but has a better name to indicate it's function:

```
public virtual void AddGraph(TEntity entity)
{
    DbSet.Add(entity);
}
```

Good Luck

**Update**

Additionally, since it looks like you are using a repository, I prefer to disable auto detect changes by setting `context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;` If you modify a property on an entity that you want persisted, you would need to set the state of the entity to modified like so:

```
public virtual void Update(TEntity entity)
{
    context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```