# How to update existing entity containing not updated sub-entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to modify entity Payment object, containing not-modified, existing Currency object and save it to EF database:

```
public Payment()
{
   int Id {get;set;}
   public int Value {get;set;}
   public Currency SelectedCurrency{get;set;}
}

public Currency()
{
    int Id {get;set;}
    string Name;
}
```

My Edit method looks like this:

```
    public override void Edit(MwbePaymentMethod payment)
    {

        if (payment.Currency != null && payment.Currency.Id != 0 && Context.Entry(payment.UserData).State != EntityState.Unchanged)
        {
            Context.Entry(payment.Currency).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
        }

        Context.Entry(payment).State = EntityState.Modified;            
    }
```

A few words about Edit method: It changes contained sub-entity Currency to Unchanged, because it;s not going to be updated. But when line

```
Context.Entry(payment).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

is called, error is displayed:

> *Attaching an entity of type 'Payment' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can
>   happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an
>   entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have
>   conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and
>   have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use
>   the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and
>   then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as
>   appropriate.*

I also tried to use `DbSet.Attach(payment)` method, but it gives error too.

ADDED1:
This is my external method which calls Edit method. It calls Context.Save and reads Payment entity by Id.

```
public void UpdateMwbePaymentMethod(MwbePaymentFilter filter, MwbePaymentDtoInOut mwbepayment)
        {
            var currentPayment = paymentMethodRepository.FindBy(x => x.UserData.Id == filter.userId && x.Id == filter.id);
            if (currentPayment==null || currentPayment.Count() != 1)
            {
                throw new DBConcurrencyException();
            }
            var mwbePayment = Mapper.Map<MwbePayment>(mwbepayment);

            mwbePayment.UserData = userRepository.Get(filter.userId).Data;            

            paymentRepository.Edit(mwbePayment);
            paymentRepository.SaveChanges();            
        }
```

ADDED2: 
I added AsNoTracking to both Find queries. I was resported as remedy. But now other entity which is marked as Detached, when method DbSet.Attach(payment) is called, it gives error

Attaching an entity of type 'MobileWallet.Common.Repository.MwbeAddress' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

ADDED 3:
Added method FindBy:

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> FindBy(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includes)
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query =  DbSet.AsNoTracking().Where(predicate);

            if (null != includes)
            {
                foreach (var include in includes)
                {
                    query = query.AsNoTracking().Include(include);
                }
            }
            IEnumerable<TEntity> result = query.AsEnumerable();
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: What ist the reason behind this? If you do not activley modify it the Currency, it will not be changed?!

Comment: do you use oracle DB?

Comment: @Technovation: Im using MS SQL Express 2013.

Comment: @Mario The Spoon: I want to update Payment object without updating existing Currency sub-object. :)

Comment: Just do context.SaveChanges() - EF will detect any changes itself. Furthermor in the second part of your comparison you use payment.UserData - this property does not even show up in your code

Comment: @Mario The Spoon: I do context.SaveChanges() in external method, but before it, the error appears:).

Comment: Is `payment` an object that is being returned from the database at an earlier location? Have you tried using `var p = Context.Find(payment);` then calling `Context.Entry(p).State = EntityState.Modified;`?

Comment: Sorry, that might need to be `var p = Context.Payments.Find(payment);`

Comment: @ jwatts1980: I added text to main post

Comment: If paymentMethodRepository is the DbContext, I would get rid of all the manipulation of the state. EF is quite able to figure it out on its own.

Comment: @Mario: So what exactly you are proposing:)?

Comment: Can you show your `FindBy` mehtod. I guess you are not getting the entity as Non-tracked, and thus when you try to change the state it throws error.

Comment: @aSharma: method added to main post

Answer (score 0):

EF6 is usually quite good at guessing what needs to be commited to the DB and what not. 
I am typically using code like this:

```
Payment payment = context.Payment.Find( 42 ); //get payment with id 42 from db

payment.Value = 199;

context.SaveChanges(); //only changed data is saved
```

**UPDATE:**
A more elaborate example:

**DbContext:**

```
class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public TestContext()
        : base()
    {}

    public DbSet<ParentEntity> Parent { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ChildEntity> Child { get; set; }    
}
```

**Parent Entity:**

```
class ParentEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; protected set; }

    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }

    public virtual ChildEntity child { get; set; } // virtual to enable lazy loading
}
```

**Child Entity:**

```
   class ChildEntity
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Value1 { get; set; }    
        public string Value2 { get; set; }
}
```

**The test code:**

```
   using ( TestContext context = new TestContext( ) )
    {
        context.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine;

        ParentEntity p1 = new ParentEntity( );
        p1.Property1 = "Value of P1";
        p1.Property2 = "Value of P2";

        ChildEntity c1 = new ChildEntity( );
        c1.Value1 = "V1";
        c1.Value2 = "V2";

        p1.child = c1;

        context.Parent.Add( p1 );

        context.SaveChanges( );

        myEntity = p1.Id;
    }

    using( TestContext context = new TestContext() )
    {
        context.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine;

        ParentEntity p = context.Parent.Where( x => x.Id == myEntity ).FirstOrDefault( );

        p.Property1 = "Changed";
        p.Property2 = "Value of P2";

        context.SaveChanges( );
    }
```

The executed sql:

> Started transaction at 28.04.2015 08:49:40 +02:00
>
> INSERT [dbo].[ChildEntities]([Value1], [Value2]) VALUES (@0, @1)
>   SELECT [Id] FROM [dbo].[ChildEntities] WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [Id] =
>   scope_identity()
>
> -- @0: 'V1' (Type = String, Size = -1)
>   -- @1: 'V2' (Type = String, Size = -1)
>   -- Executing at 28.04.2015 08:49:41 +02:00
>   -- Completed in 3 ms with result: SqlDataReader
>
> INSERT [dbo].[ParentEntities]([Property1], [Property2], [child_Id])
>   VALUES (@0, @1, @2) SELECT [Id] FROM [dbo].[ParentEntities] WHERE
>   @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [Id] = scope_identity()
>
> -- @0: 'Value of P1' (Type = String, Size = -1)
>   -- @1: 'Value of P2' (Type = String, Size = -1)
>   -- @2: '2' (Type = Int32)
>   -- Executing at 28.04.2015 08:49:41 +02:00
>   -- Completed in 3 ms with result: SqlDataReader
>
> Committed transaction at 28.04.2015 08:49:41 +02:00 Closed connection
>   at 28.04.2015 08:49:41 +02:00 Opened connection at 28.04.2015 08:49:41
>   +02:00
>
> SELECT 
>       [Limit1].[Id] AS [Id], 
>       [Limit1].[Property1] AS [Property1], 
>       [Limit1].[Property2] AS [Property2], 
>       [Limit1].[child_Id] AS [child_Id]
>       FROM ( SELECT TOP (1) 
>           [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
>           [Extent1].[Property1] AS [Property1], 
>           [Extent1].[Property2] AS [Property2], 
>           [Extent1].[child_Id] AS [child_Id]
>           FROM [dbo].[ParentEntities] AS [Extent1]
>           WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = @p__linq__0
>       )  AS [Limit1]
>
> -- p__linq__0: '2' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)
>   -- Executing at 28.04.2015 08:49:41 +02:00
>   -- Completed in 0 ms with result: SqlDataReader
>
> Closed connection at 28.04.2015 08:49:41 +02:00 Opened connection at
>   28.04.2015 08:49:41 +02:00 Started transaction at 28.04.2015 08:49:41 +02:00
>
> UPDATE [dbo].[ParentEntities] SET [Property1] = @0 WHERE ([Id] = @1)
>
> -- @0: 'Changed' (Type = String, Size = -1)
>   -- @1: '2' (Type = Int32)
>   -- Executing at 28.04.2015 08:49:41 +02:00
>   -- Completed in 5 ms with result: 1
>
> Committed transaction at 28.04.2015 08:49:41 +02:00 Closed connection
>   at 28.04.2015 08:49:41 +02:00

So as can be seen from the SQL-Log only the changed property is updated.
Be careful: 'Changed' means also assigned to the same value. So if you update from a `TextBox` check whether the value has changed before assigning it.
**UPDATE**

EF6 seems to really track the changes - an assignment with the same value does not trigger an update - see updated code

Comment: Im saving the whole object which has a lot of properties,, so I would need to do all manually:).

Comment: Yes, your code proves that there is something wrong "deeply" in my code.

Comment: And it uses BDSet .. not the whole context as yours

Comment: Sorry ;-) - but check whether you are touching properties that really did not change

Comment: But see updated comment - the value really needs to change in order to trigger an update. If you reassign the same value, it does not update the table.

Comment: WE have some generic repository with Edit & Add action, and this is not so simple as your example.